# Change indentation from 2 to 4 spaces in whole project WebStorm

Tags: typescript, webstorm, indentation

Is there a way to change the indentation of all files in my project without manually changing them per line? When I change tab and indent spacing, it doesn't change the existing indents and tabs but rather when I indent in the future if that makes sense.

Basically I want to immediately change the indentation spacing in one go for my whole project in stead of per file.

Comment: A quick search brought me to the official documentation: [Reformat and rearrange code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html) -> [Reformat code in a folder](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html#reformat_folder)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Set up the desired indent in **File | Settings | Editor | Code Style |  | Tabs and Indents**
- in the project explorer, select your project root, choose **Code | Reformat Code** from the main menu

Answer (score 6):

yes, there is a way to do it.
in WebStorm in the bottom line
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zq3o.jpg)

you may change "2" to whatever number you want. for example

[image]

and you change "2" to whatever number you want. for example,
[image]

and everywhere it will be 4 indent(if you entered 4 like me)